# How i can fix error on install storybook 7 in angular project?

Tags: angular, storybook, prettier

When i install storybook 7 in angular project  i get next error.

```
npx storybook init
```

```
 • Detecting project type. ✓
    Detected webpack project. Setting builder to webpack
 • Adding Storybook support to your "Angular" app
✔ For which project do you want to generate Storybook configuration? › scdemo
    Adding Storybook support to your "scdemo" project
✔ Do you want to use Compodoc for documentation? … yes
TypeError: overrides is not iterable
    at mergeOverrides (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/prettier/index.js:18521:32)
    at unwrapAndMerge (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/prettier/index.js:18470:75)
    at _resolveConfig (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/prettier/index.js:18483:16)
    at resolveConfig.sync (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/prettier/index.js:18488:46)
    at configureMain (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js:17:312)
    at async baseGenerator (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js:44:423)
    at async generator (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js:48:3640)
    at async doInitiate (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js:352:125)
    at async withTelemetry (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/index.js:35:3422)
    at async initiate (/Users/.npm/_npx/6fe9a9991b157df1/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js:363:109)
```

How can i fix it in my project?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?